# Spinner dropdown item out of screen

Tags: android, android-spinner

How to prevent spinner dropdown item beyond the screen? PS scrollable not function. 
spinner dropdown item beyond screen users are not able to select more item from spinner. 
Found out increase spinner height can solve the problem, but it makes design worse.
[image]

```
<ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/bank"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You can create your own custom dropdown view to a specified height.

Comment: show your spinner xml

Comment: @SagarGangawane even set height , it still out of screen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a ScrollView. It will automatically scroll if necessary.

Use something like this only:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If you follow it exactly like this in this example it will scroll just fine: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

**Basially, take out your ScrollView and LinearLayout. You don't need them.**